# Python cant figure out Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I made this program on the hand of a tutorial and ran it on my pc. it worked fine, then when trying to run the same program on qPython ( Android ) I get a syntax error which ill cp later

the program i made works out an equation.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math

a,b,c = input("Voeg de coefficienten a,b en c in; gescheiden door een komma: ")
 d = b**2-4*a*c
if d < 0:
      print "Deze vergelijking heeft geen antwoorden:"
elif d == 0:
    x = (-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
```

print "Deze vergelijking heeft 1 antwoord: ", x
    else:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
        print "Deze vergelijking heeft 2 antwoorden: ", x1, " en", x2

Now the error i get is:
     x = (-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The syntax error points to the "))"
probably a stupid problem i just cant figure out.. , but any suggestions?

Comment: @bigOTHER: Please don't make indentation changes like that on Python questions. (In this case, that change would have been a bad idea regardless of language, since you removed non-ASCII characters that would have caused a syntax error in a lot of languages.)

Comment: @user2357112 How do you mean exactly? at first when having it set to the standard encoding ( - the utf-8 line ) it would give me an encoding error. So i looked up how to fix that and that worked. but this happened, could you suggest as to how to fix this? I am still new to this :/ Sorry for that.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: Don't do that. You're removing the bug.

Comment: It's the same number of spaces, unless the issue is a non-standard space character and I'm an idiot.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: That is exactly the issue.

Comment: @user2357112 Got it! I never would've thought to even check that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There appears to be an extra space before the d? Also, noting as you already calculate what d is, you do not need to recalculate it in the elif branch :). The other thing to ensure is that you're not running Python 3 in qPython, since print statements now need brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code seems to have some Unicode non-breaking spaces in it instead of regular spaces. Retype it, and it should work fine. (There's also that extra space in front of the `d`, which you said isn't in your actual code, but then you deleted the comment. In any case, that space shouldn't be there either.)

You may want to try to figure out what you did to get those weird spaces into your code and avoid doing that in the future. I can't tell you what that would have been.